# Get compiled .class output directory in Android Gradle task

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, source-sets

I'm creating a Gradle task for my Android project that needs to know the path to the compiled `.class` files. How can I get this path? I've found suggestions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26667774/3004881) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19927627/3004881); also see [the Gradle docs for `SourceSet`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/SourceSet.html)) that `sourceSets.main.output.classDir` will give me this path, but when I try to use it, I get the error

> Could not find property `'output'` on source set `main`.

This happens even when I create a new, minimal project, with the following `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    task printClassesDir << {
        println sourceSets.main.output.classesDir
    }
}
```

This minimal project builds fine, but will give that error if I run the task `printClassesDir`. How can I get the `.class` file output directory in my task?

---

I've also tried the suggestion of `<build variant>.javaCompile.classpath` from [this answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28224687/3004881). I was able to access this property with

```
applicationVariants.find{it.name == 'debug'}.javaCompile.classpath
```

but this file collection is empty.

---

For reference, here are the other files for my minimal project:

#### `src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="a.b">
  <uses-sdk
      android:minSdkVersion="9"
      android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
  <application>
    <activity android:name=".Main">
      <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

#### `src/main/java/a/b/Main.java`

```
package a.b;
import android.app.Activity;
public class Main extends Activity { }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to find this path using the `compile<Variant>JavaWithJavac` tasks. These are of type [JavaCompile](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.html), so they have `destinationDir` properties:

```
task printDebugClassesDir << {
    println compileDebugJavaWithJavac.destinationDir
}
```

This prints the `build/intermediates/classes/debug` directory, which contains the compiled class files. The same thing works for release.

Comment: How to get the output  of a source set?